# creating a bash alias name that contains an =

Tags: 14.04, bashrc

I am trying to set up a `~/.bash_aliases` that worked in 12.04 but now bash complains about the `=` sign.

```
alias emacs = 'emacsclient -c -a --socket-name=server --alternate-editor='
```

How can I set this up?

What I am told:

```
bash: alias: emacs: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: `emacsclient -c -a --socket-name': invalid alias name
```

If I type it in directly with no alias, it works and opens emacs

[image]

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @udiboy1209 add to op

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces around the `=` sign.  Here is how it should be:

```
alias emacs='emacsclient -c -a --socket-name=server --alternate-editor='
```